# Trigger onProperty of component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have tried to trigger (refer, call, correct terminology?) an onScale from the property of this  component from the react-native-photo-view API:

```
<PhotoView
    source={{ uri:  }}
    onLoad={() => console.log('onLoad called')}
    onTap={(event) =>
    console.log(`onTap called: ${event.nativeEvent.x}${event.nativeEvent.y}`)}
    onScale={() => console.log('onScale called')}
    minimumZoomScale={1}
    maximumZoomScale={3}
    scale={0.5}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
    androidScaleType={'fitXY'}
    style={styles.photo}
/>
```

How could i "trigger" this `onScale={}` property from lets say a `<Button onClick={triggerOnScale()} />` to zoom with the scale factor? Any direct code example or pointers to techniques/methods that could help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If onScale is a method of your PhotoView component then you can set up a reference to call it:

```
handleOnClick = () => this.photoView.onScale()
//just use the handleOnClick wherever you want your click and it will call onScale also

   <PhotoView
        source={{ uri:  }}
        onLoad={() => console.log('onLoad called')}
        onTap={(event) =>
        console.log(`onTap called: ${event.nativeEvent.x}${event.nativeEvent.y}`)}
        **ref={(photoView) => this.photoView = photoView}**
        minimumZoomScale={1}
        maximumZoomScale={3}
        scale={0.5}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
        androidScaleType={'fitXY'}
        style={styles.photo}
    />
```

Comment: I was perhaps a bit unclear in my question, the <PhotoView> component is not mine, i edited my question.

Comment: The way they set it up is that when something scales it will call the onScale callback function...Not sure why you would want a button click to 'trigger it'. If you explain more on what you're trying to accomplish maybe we can help more but the answer above is also another choice - to just have both of them trigger the same function.

Comment: Oh that's right, I actually did not get that! Thanks for pointing that out for me!

Comment: np, if you were trying to change the scale on button click you should use a state variable for the scale property and have the button click change that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your onScale handler and your button's onClick handler to fire the same function, then you can just bind a function to the containing component and then pass the function's reference to the Button and PhotoView respectively.

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
  }

  someFunction() {
    console.log('Inside some Function.);
  }

  render() {
    return(
     <div>
       <PhotoView onScale={this.someFunction} />
       <Button onClick={this.someFunction} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```